# Update column of one table from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I need to update one column of table with other from same table

```
UPDATE table 
SET table1.name = table1.nickname
FROM table 
WHERE userid = 5
```

Is there any problem in my query, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're adding some syntax you don't need...if all the data you need is already there in that table, simply do like so, regardless of which flavor of SQL (I think; I could be wrong on that part):

`UPDATE dbo.tablename
 SET columnToChange = columnWithCorrectValue
 WHERE userid = 5`

Comment: my pleasure @youv :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need to remove `From table` part from your syntax.

Answer (score 1):

two things your are doing wrong:

1. Update query is wrong, i means syntax
2. Second, you are trying to update table1 instead of table

your query should be:

```
UPDATE table
SET table.name = table.nickname
WHERE table.userid = 5
```

OR

```
UPDATE table
SET name = nickname
WHERE table.userid = 5
```

for more info regarding the syntax for update in sql server, please [check this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)